# Inno Setup: ensure that the user have read the Information page

Tags: inno-setup

I have an `Information` page, the page that that is activated with *infobefore* file:

```
[Setup]
InfoBeforeFile=infobefore.txt
```

I want to:

- Add a checkbox (or a couple of checkboxes), that the user has to check to show that he has paid attention to the information.
- The user should only be allowed to proceed when he checks the checkboxes right. I think of disabling the *Next* button or showing a messagebox, whatever is easier.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a new checkbox on the `InfoBeforePage` page. And update the `NextButton` state based on the check box state.

```pascal
[Setup]
InfoBeforeFile=infobefore.txt

[Code]

var
  InfoBeforeCheck: TNewCheckBox;

procedure CheckInfoBeforeRead;
begin
  { Enable the NextButton only if InfoBeforeCheck is checked or }
  { installer is running in the silent mode }
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := InfoBeforeCheck.Checked or WizardSilent;
end;

procedure InfoBeforeCheckClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Update state of the Next button, whenever the InfoBeforeCheck is toggled }
  CheckInfoBeforeRead;
end;  

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  InfoBeforeCheck := TNewCheckBox.Create(WizardForm);
  InfoBeforeCheck.Parent := WizardForm.InfoBeforePage;
  { Follow the License page layout }
  InfoBeforeCheck.Top := WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Top;
  InfoBeforeCheck.Left := WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Left;
  InfoBeforeCheck.Width := WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Width;
  InfoBeforeCheck.Height := WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Height;
  InfoBeforeCheck.Caption := 'I swear I read this';
  InfoBeforeCheck.OnClick := @InfoBeforeCheckClick;

  { Make the gap between the InfoBeforeMemo and the InfoBeforeCheck the same }
  { as the gap between LicenseMemo and LicenseAcceptedRadio }
  WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.Height :=
    ((WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Top + WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height) -
     WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.Top) +
    (InfoBeforeCheck.Top - WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Top);
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpInfoBefore then
  begin
    { Initial state of the Next button }
    CheckInfoBeforeRead;
  end;
end;
```

[image: I swear I read this]

Comment: I came up with the exact same solution with [this commit](https://github.com/spikespaz/search-deflector/commit/bcf19f12a1d1fceaaf5a773557b11ceb7a0c0a4d).